# Diag of Matrix Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

How to proof the following equation:
$$Diag(U^*PU)_{qq}=\sum_{l,m=0}U_{lq}P_{lm}U_{mq}$$

I could work out the $$(U^*PU)_{qq}$$ part, but could not understant the diag means? Thank you!

Comment: Diag stands for diagonal.  These are the diagonal entries of $U^*PU$.

Comment: Thanks, but why it's the diagonal entries of $$U^*PU$$

Comment: The $qq$ matrix elements are on the diagonal.

Comment: Ohhh, I see. Thank you!